# The import org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator cannot be resolved and The import org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

After migrating to the `hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final` jar, I'm trying to use the `ClassValidator` class.

But the import `org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator<User.class>` is not getting resolved.

I also have the compatible dependencies `org.hibernate.hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final` and  `org.hibernate.hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final`

before migrating to the `hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final` jar, there were no issues with the `ClassValidator<User.class>`

Earlier I had the dependencies `org.hibernate.hibernate-annotations:3.2.0.GA` and
`org.hibernate.hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final`, it was working well

I am not understanding the issue. How do I resolve the errors with `hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final` and `hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final`, which are the suggested dependency jar in my demo project?

Please help me with this

Comment: try printing a dependency tree and find out what all you are including in your jar. Try to remove duplicates of hibernate-validator.

Comment: thks for ur comment, I did not find any duplicates of hibernate-validator from my projects dependency tree.

Comment: trying to find the alternate for the ClassValidator class, and few other annotaions(@Length, @Notnull, @Email) which are failing due to the hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final jar.